# What is the best graphical simulator for 68K microprocessor?

Tags: simulator, 68000

I am a beginner and I need a graphical simulator to write assembly programs based on 68000 microprocessor. I have found Easy68K simulator. It works and the features are good, but is there any newer/better graphical simulator than Easy68K? I need the most uptodate one.

Comment: or what is the last version no. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latest version of EASy68K emulator is v5.12.29 at the moment. You can find this information (and follow the updates) at [EASy68K forums](http://www.easy68k.com/EASy68Kforum/index.php). You can download latest version from the URL below;

http://www.easy68k.com/

If you want some graphical simulation, you may like to use an emulator of a computer using 68K CPU like `Commodore Amiga` or `Atari ST`. I prefer [UAE](http://www.amigaemulator.org/) Amiga emulator. Of course you need to learn about Amiga hardware and stuff but you may also like the experience, test your 68k routines, see or hear the output.

My advice may not be suitable for your needs. But you already know about EASy68K and i know no better way than Amiga/Atari ST emulators myself.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to display. If you want to be able to control each individual pixel, don't use Sega Genesis or Neo Geo, as they're tile-based. But they have dedicated hardware for easily displaying multiple layers of graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [BSVC](https://github.com/BSVC/bsvc).

But this depends on what you mean by "graphical" simulator...BSVC has a graphical user interface, but doesn't simulate graphics.  Hope that helps!